# PHP CodeIgniter (how to make public folder)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm a new in CodeIgniter.

I made public folder, where I want to put my css/js/images folders.

My setup is like that:

```
application
   cache
   config
   controllers
   public
       css
       js
       images
  ....
  ....
  ....
```

My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /moviesmvc/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

how can I make this public folder public?

/////////////////////////

Comment: I usualylly use this method. But, I never used a rule in **`.htaccess`** file. Try moving the **`public`** folder outside of the **`application`** folder. Put it in the root.

Comment: http://localhost/moviesmvc/application/public/css/resset.css 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: No point in adding a Localhost link as no one can see this except yourself. It's based entirely on your PC.

Comment: Move the public folder like I said and try the url as localhost/moviesmvc/public/css/resset.css

Answer (score 1):

You **really don't want to** put your public folder inside your application folder.  Your directory structure should be like this

```
 -- application
 -- system
 -- public
    -- css
    -- js
    -- images
    -- index.php
    -- .htaccess
```

This is the best practice to follow and you will save yourself a lot of time and potential problems in the future

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Linux server then you need to change the folder permissions to 755 or 777. Have a Google around for this and you will get a lot more detail.

I would recommend not using CI at the minute as it isn't being developed on any more until they find a new owner. Instead, I would recommend Laravel as it's such an amazing framework, but you should also try out CakePHP, Symfony, Yii or something else which is still being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Public Folder Permission as well as use base_url() function to get the public url..

for example

```
echo base_url('public/images'); to get image public path
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise to implement this type of design and here is why:

- Web servers are designed to not allow public access below the document root. This aides in both ease-of-setup and security.
- If a major security change is made within the root then it has to be duplicated to your public folder.
- You are adding unnecessary processing to **EVERY** HTTP/HTTPS call to your web server because now the rules have to be processed for every request. If you could build this into your `httpd.conf` file instead then the overhead is nearly non-existent.

**TL;DR;**

No need to re-invent the wheel by adding a lump around the perimeter.